# Авторские права на используемый в своем проекте чужой код

Tags: лицензирование, opensource, авторские-права

Если я в части своего проекта использую кусок кода, взятый из свободного доступа без указания на него лицензии, то нарушил ли я какие-либо установленные законом рамки?

Или должен ли я указать в своем проекте автора, чей кусок кода я взял?
И имеет ли он право требовать с меня обязательного указания своего соавторства, если в том месте, где я брал код, не было явно указано его авторство?

Может ли он потребовать убрать, не использовать его наработки?
Как можно доказать свое авторство на код, свободно размещенный в интернете?
Если мой код очень похож на код какого-то разработчика, и он выражает свое недовольство? Как быть в этом случае?

Как понять, где начинаются и заканчиваются рамки авторского права, относительно исходного кода?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если код просто выложен на сайт без лицензии, то вы не можете использовать его никак, кроме как просто читать: авторские права остаются за автором кода, и только он может определять, что с его кодом можно делать. Полностью определять. Таким образом, если автор захочет, он может *потребовать*, чтобы вы указали его соавтором; а может *потребовать*, чтобы не указывали; также он может *запретить* использовать свой код (например, сказав, что код выложен только в обучающих целях). Всё в руках автора.

Если код выложен без лицензии, это означает, что автор просто не удосужился сообщить свои условия использования кода, а вовсе не то, что код можно использовать на ваше усмотрение. Обратитесь к автору за разъяснением.

Существует понятие "общественного достояния" (public domain), что означает, что автор отказывается от своих прав на код, и любой может делать с этим кодом всё, что хочет. Но в таком случае это должно быть *явно* написано на сайте. Кстати, насколько я знаю, в России нельзя отказаться от авторских прав, то есть нельзя передать своё творение в общественное достояние - оно может стать общественным достоянием только через 70 лет после смерти автора.

В любом случае, если лицензия кода не указана, стоит обратиться к автору напрямую, и узнать условия использования его кода. Если ваш проект серьёзный и большой, то эти условия желательно ещё и юридически оформить, чтобы не было проблем в дальнейшем.

Насчёт похожих кодов, и "где начинаются и заканчиваются рамки". В некотором роде философский вопрос. Здесь, на мой взгляд, ничего нельзя сказать, кроме следующего циничного высказывания: в суде доказать можно всё, что захочешь, если есть адвокаты и деньги. Некоторые пытаются прочитать закон сотню раз, чтобы понять великую идею, которая была в нём заложена, и затем логически непротиворечиво вывести эти самые рамки. Законодатели пытаются упомянуть в законе все возможные случаи, которые только могут быть (а авторы программ пишут огромные тексты лицензий, где написано всё на все случаи жизни) - и всё равно и те, и другие что-нибудь просмотрят, и получится зацепка, с помощью которой можно будет толковать закон/лицензию неоднозначно. Идеализированные представления об авторском праве, защите интеллектуальной собственности и вообще, о *праве*, на мой взгляд, не имеют никакой рациональной основы, и противоречат сами себе. (Анархизм, да; и вообще спорный вопрос, поэтому не буду продолжать).

Поэтому: не полагайтесь на ваше суждение о вещах, которые автор умолчал - напрямую спросите его об этом; юридически оформляйте всё, что только можно; имейте деньги и адвокатов.

Comment: Если ваш вопрос слегка утрировать и написать `for(int i=0; i<10; i++)`, то можно сказать, что это мой код и никто не может его использовать. Я сам лично много раз писал код и алгоритмы с подобной реализацией которых, сталкивался в интернете, и что теперь я похитил чужую собственность?

Comment: Вот как раз на этот случай есть философская часть моего ответа.
Похитили вы или нет - зависит от определения слова похитили. Отвечая на вопрос, я исходил из практически-юридического определения: вы похитили, если так решит суд. А суд теоретически может вас осудить даже за один цикл for - так как грань между кодом, который можно написать, потому что "все же пишут, и я много раз писал", и тем, который будет считаться украденным, из законов не ясна.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Ваш ответ дал существенное прояснение.

Answer (score -1):

Ключевые слова: свободный доступ, отсутствие лицензии.
Доказать то, что это его код он не сможет ни коим образом. Код у нас пока не патентуется.

Но с моей точки зрения, указывать или нет его в авторах это дело вашей совести.

Comment: Если это был код GPL, то нет, вы оба неправы. Т.к. любой код, содержащий GPL код, должен быть под GPL лицензией. Это как вирус. Be carefull!<p>
Это если вот так на примитивном уровне объяснять. Реально же по факту нужно смотреть лицензию, договариваться с автором(-ами) программы в частном порядке.<p>
<i>Код у нас пока не патентуется.</i><p>
Но это не мешает зарегистрировать программу и авторские права на нее.<p>
<i>Доказать то, что это его код он не сможет ни коим образом</i><p>
Дизассемблировать и доказать идентичность алгоритмов проблемы не представляет в случае, если это того стоит.

Comment: Насчёт дизассемблирования - полегче. Мы-то живём в цивилизованной стране, в вот на диком Западе это, кажись, может рассматриваться как преступление.

Comment: @gecube, Вы читаете вопрос? "взятый из свободного доступа (без указания на него лицензии)", откуда возьмется тогда GPL? 
"Но это не мешает зарегистрировать программу и авторские права на нее.", вы много программиного кода зарегистрировали? 
"Дизассемблировать и доказать идентичность алгоритмов проблемы не представляет в случае, если это того стоит", ага, а если два человека написала идентичный алгоритм, то это всегда значит, что один из них врет и скорее всего не тот, кто пришел жаловаться первым?

Comment: <b>alexlz</b>,<p>
<i>в вот на диком Западе это, кажись, может рассматриваться как преступление.</i><p>
На цивилизованном Западе не считают некорректным в рамках борьбы с терроризмом прослушивать простых граждан. А потом эти 'улики' использовать на деле.<p>
<b>Dex</b>,
<i>откуда возьмется тогда GPL?</i>
Высосанный пример из пальца: всем известно, что в сеть утекли исходники M$ Windows, KAV и пр. известных программных продуктов. Можно найти эти файлы. А можно найти фрагменты кода без указания на то откуда они взяты. Но от этого они исходными кодами этих продуктов не перестанут быть.

Comment: Поэтому использовать в коммерческом продукте взятый абы откуда код чревато. К тому же там могут быть ошибки и закладки. С другой стороны, для личного использование - можно делать вообще все что заблагорассудиться.<p>
<i>вы много программиного кода зарегистрировали?</i><p>
К делу не относится.<p>
<i>а если два человека написала идентичный алгоритм, то это всегда значит, что один из них врет и скорее всего не тот, кто пришел жаловаться первым?</i><p>
Патент на bubble sorting звучит, конечно, глупо :-D Но вот на какой-нибудь алгоритм шифрования - почему бы и нет?

Comment: <i>а если два человека написала идентичный алгоритм, то это всегда значит, что один из них врет и скорее всего не тот, кто пришел жаловаться первым?</i><p>
Патент на bubble sorting звучит, конечно, глупо :-D Но вот на какой-нибудь алгоритм шифрования - почему бы и нет?

Comment: @gecube, вы правы, тоже думал об этом, но доказать это весьма сложно, я же не думаю, что в вопросе фигурируют гиганты софта. Ну и если человек будет использовать только для себя, он не нарушает закона. А при продаже надо все же озаботиться лицензией.

Comment: Постойте, патент на алгоритм это одно, а на код совершенно другое.