# Авторское право в программировании (Интеллектуальная собственность)

Tags: лицензирование, авторские-права

У меня есть программа , она преследует какую то идею соответственно. Тут какой-то программист Вася Пупкин из другого конца страны увидел мою программу и сделал тоже самое (может с какими то улучшениями) назвал её также и распространяет её, и получает мою славу.

Что кроме "карма" может помешать это сделать? Или может каким-то образом я смогу уберечь программу (зарегистрировать авторские права)? Или этот вопрос абсурд?

Вообще поясните если я что-то не понимаю. Может оно и правда не надо?

Comment: Разделите реализацию (програмный код, изображения, иконки, звуки) и идею - идеи нигде не патентуются даже в США. Нельзя запатентовать абстрактный текстовый редактор, проигрыватель видео или какую-то РПГ. Сам код - пожалуйста. Причем в России код автоматически считается авторским произведением и права автора защищаются.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Программа есть и всегда была интеллектуальной собственностью. Поэтому только подходя к этому вопросу с данной стороны можно пытаться судиться. Но доказать, что код ваш практически невозможно. Грубо говоря вы даже не имеете права без разрешения автора использовать в своих программах простейшие циклы, которые вы нашли в книге, например:

```
for(int i=0; i<var; i++) doSomth();
```

Что касается патентов, вы всегда можете зарегистрировать свое творение за границей. Естественно патент будет не действителен в России или других странах в зависимости от того, где патентовались, зато Василий Пупкин уже не сможет продавать данную программу в стране, патент которой вы получили.

Что касается торговых марок и названий, их так же можно регистрировать. Обычно существуют локальные регистры (например на страну), а есть глобальные, как приводили пример, Apple, товарный знак, торговая марка уже зарегистрирована и использовать ее нельзя. Но только для продукции той же специфики. Т.е., например, если вы собираете яблоки и называете себя Apple, вы так же можете зарегистрировать эту торговую марку и она будет вполне легальна и совершенно не будет идти в противовес существующей.

Регистрировать сам код тоже считаю бессмысленным, снова повторюсь, даже если он зарегистрирован, доказать что у вас код передрали будет очень проблематично.

**UPD**

Вот еще есть [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/11061/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0) и ответ к нему, который хорошо иллюстрирует то, что происходит с кодом автора. @quyse абсолютно прав, общался я с юристом по этому вопросу.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. =)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, очень познавательно...

Answer (score 0):

Если ты придумал что-то новое, то единственный способ защитить права - патент. Причем читал как-то, что коды в России не патентуются. Можно запатентовать новые технологии. А иначе - никак. Хотя я не юрист, может, и не прав.

А вообще, нужно больше думать о благе человечества.

Comment: Когда берут идею и присваивают себе...Как бэ...Невольно думаешь о Оружейном Магазине по соседству...А не как не о "благе человечества" :DD

Comment: Если бы так всю историю человечества изобретатели думали, то мы бы до сих пор жили бы в каменном веке. В буквальном смысле.

Comment: Любовь к миру должна быть взаимной. В описываемом случае можно и по голове стукнуть монтировкой без нарушения вселенского равновесия. Особенно если прога платная и изначальный разработчик этим зарабатывает. Ну и вы пытаетесь прикрыть вора - надеюсь, неосознанно.

Comment: И опять же, если идея не защищена патентом, то обижаться не на что. А монтировкой по голове - получишь срок. 

В общем, если придумываешь что-то стОящее, сразу надо патентовать. Иначе ничего не добьешься.

Comment: Это как так? %) То есть если у Вас есть девушка и вы с ней не женаты и её похитили то обижаться не на что? :DDDD Извиняюсь за столь странный пример но всё же... :DDD

Comment: Пообижаться, конечно, можно, но только в плане личных переживаний. Если девушку похитили бандиты с целью выкупа - это одно. Тут статья и все такое. А если она добровольно ушла к другому - ну можно, конечно, морду набить, но это, боюсь, ничего не изменит.

Comment: Кроме привычки быть "терпилой" =)
Моя логика проста. Делать "бесплатные копии" коммерческих продуктов подло. 1) автор теряет деньги, 2) "копирователь" не создает ничего нового, 3) бесплатный продукт *хуже* платного. Мб есть исключения, но я их не встречал. 

В итоге халявщики считают, что прогерам деньги не нужны, вор получает славу бравого толераста-пацифиста, а прогер сидит без бабла, потому что в отличие от вора он зарабатывает на софте, а не работает в конторе папы, получая за верстку визиток 70k/мес.

Comment: Речь вообще не об этом. Речь не о воровстве программ, а о законности использования идей. И о том, как сохранить свои права на интеллектуальную собственность.

Comment: Хороший съезд, только последнее предложение вашего ответа как бы намекает, что вы в подобном угоне именно идеи не видите ничего плохого. Я просто высказался о том, что таких угонщиков надо наказывать и объяснил, почему я так считаю. Даже не для вас, а чтобы будущие читатели взвесили все аргументы за и против)

А да, и сроками меня пугать не надо. Есть законы природы, все остальное - угрозы и рекомендации. Я просто всегда стараюсь действовать честно и разумно, если за это светит срок - грустно, но не более.

Comment: Реалии мирового бытия несколько сложнее, что касается программ тут вообще все просто, она или нужна и именно ТЫ на ней зарабатываешь либо она не нужна и тогда уже пофиг.

@Sh4dow все это очнь красиво написано и я бы "возверовал" бы в эти слова если бы Билл Гейтса засудили ( для тех кто не в теме к чему я это - гугл или фильм "пираты силиконовой долины" ).

В целом и @Sh4dow и @mikillskegg в чем-то правы и в чем-то не правы.

PS: правильного ответа тут нет и быть не может, т.к. вопрос из разряда "философских"

Comment: Есть...Носить с собой монтировку и иногда в УК заглядывать :DDDD А насчёт платного ПО я с @sh4dow согласен...Да мне кажется все согласны...Только боюсь не кто не бежит за кошелём когда видит красивую прогу в интернете...А торенты не успевают закрывать :DDDDDD 


ps. Но это уже другая история ^^

Answer (score 0):

Тогда был бы у нас один гугл, и ни каких яндексов, и тому подобное. И да запатентовать "код" в России никак. да и как бы мы жили с таким - одни монополисты бы были :) здоровая конкуренция всегда хороша)) 
**udp:** на счет одинаковых названий не в курсе но, в России например мильон ООО могут иметь одинаковые названия :) а вот каким-нибудь эплом назвать уже нельзя, фактически то можно, но примерно какой-нить магазинчик в деревне)

Comment: ну у нас нельзя получить патент на код как на интелектуальную собсвенность (как нпример в штатах)

Comment: Я сказал "в России", потому что про другие страны просто не знаю.

Comment: А вообще я слышал что если сделали программу, имеете к ней исходный код, и дали ей название то как бы больше нечего не надо...можно правда пойти зарегистрировать права но это будет только для государства (типа учёт) и для понтов :DDD

Comment: Не знаю, не скажу.

Comment: ООО и Корпорация я так понимаю имеют разные права...Поэтому Эплом назвать и нельзя...ибо "корпорэйшн"

Comment: Я думаю, тебе лучше обратиться на какой-нибудь юридический форум. Или к знакомому юристу.

Comment: В России нет корпораций, точнее есть это наверное ОАО. на счет прва на программу тоже кажется нельзя просто нет в нашем законодательстве слово программа, ну есть точнее что-то связаное с ЭВМ но это фигня там какая-то :)

Comment: Так и сделаю) Но мало ли здесь кто нибудь есть знакомый с этим...

Comment: так ты идею то вылаживай - мы тебе посоветуем))

Comment: Ааааага....Щааааааас.... :DDD